# javascript outside of scope

Tags: javascript, scope

Based on chrome developer tools a breakpoints I think I'm dealing with a scope issue I can figure out.  Is it the way I define the function?  The script below is an include js file and the array ' timeStamp I want available for use in other functions without having to call my loadData function everytime.

The timeStamp array goes undefined once it leaves the for loop before it even leaves the function.

```
var timeStamp = [];  // Want this array to be global

function loadData (url){

        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

            for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
                    timeStamp.push(json[i].TimeStamp);  
                }
                    console.log(inputBITS); //returns the value
            });
        console.log(inputBITS); //undefined
        }
```

Thank you for anyhelp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that `getJSON` is asynchronous.  When it executes and finishes and your code continues on, it indicates only the START of the networking operation to retrieve the data.  The actual networking operation does not complete until some time later.

When it does complete, the success handler is called (as specified as the second argument to your `getJSON()` call) and you populate the `timeStamp` array.  ONLY after that success handler has been called is the `timeStamp` array valid.

As such, you cannot use the `timeStamp` array in code that immediately follows the `getJSON()` call (it hasn't been filled in yet).  If other code needs the `timeStamp` array, you should call that code from the success handler or use some other timing mechanism to make sure that the code that uses the `timeStamp` array doesn't try to use it until AFTER the success handler has been called and the `timeStamp` array has been populated.

It is possible to make some Ajax calls be synchronous instead of asynchronous, but that is generally a very bad idea because it locks up the browser during the entire networking operation which is very unfriendly to the viewer.  It is much better to fix the coding logic to work with asynchronous networking.

A typical design pattern for an ajax call like this is as follows:

```
function loadData (url){

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        // this will execute AFTER the ajax networking finishes
        var timeStamp = [];
        for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
                timeStamp.push(json[i].TimeStamp);  
        }
        console.log(timeStamp);
        // now call other functions that need timeStamp data
        myOtherFunc(timeStamp);
     });
     // this will execute when the ajax networking has just been started
     //
     // timeStamp data is NOT valid here because 
     // the ajax call has not yet completed
     // You can only use the ajax data inside the success handler function
     // or in any functions that you call from there
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Going to check out success handlers.

Comment: @rd42 - You already have a success handler.  It's the anonymous function that's declared as the second argument to your getJSON call.  It's a function called when the ajax call finishes successfully.  It is called some time later after the ajax networking is done.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. both console.logs() are in the function but only one is defined and the second console.log() doesn't get called until after the array is loaded, right?

Comment: @rd42 - the second `console.log()` you have gets called as soon as the `getJSON()` call is done with it's initial execution.  At that point, the ajax network has NOT completed and the success handler has NOT been called and the `timeStamp` array has not been filled.

Comment: thanks again, that's the asynchronous part I didn't catch in your first explanation.  ... and that's why I put the function caslls in the call back part.

Answer (score 2):

<del>And here's another person who doesn't understand basic AJAX...</del>

`getJSON` is ***asynchronous***. Meaning, code keeps running after the function call and before the successful return of the JSON request.

You can "fix" this by forcing the request to be synchronous with an appropriate flag, but that's a really bad idea for many reasons (the least of which is that you're violating the basic idea of **A**�JAX). The best way is to remember how AJAX works and instead put all your code that should be executed when the AJAX returns, in the right place.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there another term besides 'right place' I can google?

Comment: Just put it in the anonymous function you defined, where you see the correct value for the variable being logged.